# Page returning a different content when parsed

Tags: http, parsing

I have to parse this page:

http://muoversiaroma.it/paline/percorso/52732?nav=3

if normally accessed by a browser, it returns the correct contents, but if I try to parse it with:
@file_get_html($url) or file_get_html
it returns a totally different content that seems like a default page. What might they have inserted in the page to protect it, if that is the case, and how may I overcome it?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is almost certainly with headers. Here's what you can do to test (Note: I used `file_get_contents()` instead of `file_get_html()` since I don't have the [simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library, but the results should be comparable):

1) Create a file on your PHP server called "test.php" with these contents (you can use another port instead of 9002, if you like):

```
<?=file_get_html('http://localhost:9002/');?>
```

2) From the terminal, run netcat in listen mode on whatever port you used above:

```
nc -lp9002
```

3) In your browser, hit the test page: `http://YOUR_SITE.com/PATH/test.php`. Netcat will show you what headers the HTML parser is sending:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: 192.168.1.127:9002
```

4) Now close netcat (`CTRL+C`) and then start it again like in step 2.

5) This time hit that port directly from the browser: `http://YOUR_SITE.com:9002/`. Now, Netcat will show you what headers your browser is sending:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: harveyserv.ath.cx:9002
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

So the issue you're having could be anything among these differences, but for starters, you can look at the fact that `file_get_contents()` sends an HTTP 1.0 request while most browsers today use HTTP 1.1 (this also corresponds to the "Connection: keep-alive" header). Also a lot of sites send different content based on the "User-Agent" and "Accept" headers.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Luckily Atac has a beta web site at http://beta.muovi.roma.it that gives much better error messages and so clarified to my request that the new version also expects an agent. Once I provided one both the beta and the main version got correctly parsed.
That is the relevant piece of code:

```
$someUA = array (
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; fr; rv:1.9.1b1) Gecko/20081007 Firefox/3.1b1",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.0",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/0.4.154.18 Safari/525.19",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.27 Safari/525.13",
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)",
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.40607)",
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)",
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; Media Center PC 3.1; Alexa Toolbar; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
"Mozilla/45.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)",
"Mozilla/4.08 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)",
"Mozilla/4.01 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
);

function getRandomUserAgent() {
   srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
   global $someUA;
   return $someUA[rand(0,count($someUA)-1)];
 }


function atac_get_html($url, $language){
//$url='http://muovi.roma.it/paline/palina/77113?nav=4'; //manual forcing
set_include_path("/iPhone/simplehtmldom_1_5");
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('atacurl.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
//$atacurl=atacurl();
//$languageUrl=$atacurl."/lingua/set/".$language;

$languageUrl="http://muovi.roma.it/lingua/set/en";
if (!isset($_SESSION['ckfile'])) {
    $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $_SESSION['ckfile']=$ckfile;
/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */
    $ch = curl_init ($languageUrl);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, getRandomUserAgent());
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);
}
}
$ckfile=$_SESSION['ckfile'];
 /* STEP 3. visit cookiepage.php */
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, getRandomUserAgent());
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
return str_get_html($output);
}
```